# How to change back year that change into 2000 after using date format

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdateformatter

hi I want to  get current hour and minute from **Date()**, so I need to format it into string and want to bring back into date again. But after I try to convert to date the year change into 2000, how can I got back to current year.

```
//date formatter
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current


    // Get current time and format it to compare
    var currentTime = Date() //Get current time
    let currentTimeStr = dateFormatter.string(from: currentTime) //get current time only hour and minute
    currentTime = dateFormatter.date(from: currentTimeStr)! //this is where the problem because the year change into 1 January 2000
```

[image]

Comment: add your code instead of image so that others can copy and edit

Comment: @AwaisFayyaz wait I edit my question

Comment: Use `DateComponents`

Comment: @Gereon how? isn't that if I use DateComponents it get separate hour and minute, I want to get both "13:11"

Comment: Why do you need to turn the string into a `Date` again? You already have the date. It is stored in `currentTime`.

Comment: @Sweeper I only want the hour and minute since the date is store an info of year, month, date, and time. since I want to get the time only

Comment: @ferryawijayanto So why is the date being in 2000 a problem for you? You only care about the time right?

Comment: @Sweeper I want to change background with specific time, and the time I get is a string time array so I want to change background from current time and string time array.

Comment: in last line, you need current date ?

Answer (score 1):

From what I read in the comments, I think you want both the current time in a Date object and also a string with only hours and minutes in `"HH:MM"` format.

The problem comes from trying to use a formatter that doesn't have a year specified. You are overwriting the `currentTime` from a string that doesn't have a year (or day, or month) defined, so it defaults to Jan 1st 2000 (the hours and minutes should be correct).

You're also saying you need to format it into a String, and then go back to a Date object. *You don't*, you already have all the data you need in the Date object, so keep it around and use it when you need to. If this means creating a bunch of `DateFormatters` all over your project, you can always extend `Date` to have a function or variable that returns the string with the format you want.

```
extension Date {
  var hoursAndMinutesString: String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
  }
}
```

Then just call the function from the Date object when you need to, like this:

```
currentTime.hoursAndMinutesString
```